# how do I initiate a debug session for android application from the command line?

Tags: android, debugging, command-line

I am using eclipse and would like to launch a debug session for my android executable (apk) from the command line.

Said another way - instead of pushing the debug button in the eclipse interface, I'd like to startup the debug session via the command line.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html):

> If you are not using Eclipse to develop, you can still take advantage of all the tools that the Android SDK provides for debugging. A basic debugging environment consists of:
>
> - ADB
> - DDMS
> - Java Debugger
>
> You need to obtain a JDWP-compliant Java debugger to properly debug your application. Most Java IDEs will already have one included, or you can use a command line debugger, such as JDB, if you are using a simple text editor to develop applications.

JDB seems to come standard with the JDK.